# select a value based on a range of values in each row Excel

Tags: excel, vba, function, input

[Selection based on a range of values in each row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glXxI.jpg)

**To: Stack overflow**

1) I wish to draft a code that allows a value to be selected based on a **range of values in each row** as indicated in the picture.
My preliminary code below is:-

```
Private SubWorksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub 
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F7,H7,J7")) Is Nothing Then Me.Range("C7").Value = Target.Value
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F8, H8, J8")) Is Nothing Then Me.Range("C8").Value = Target.Value End If  
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F9, H9, J9, L9")) Is Nothing Then Me.Range("C9").Value = Target.Value
End If 
End Sub
```

2)  Because I  have more than 100 rows of selections to be input, the said code on the above will be tediously wordy.
3) I would appreciate it if you could advise me how to refine and make it beautiful. Thank you very much.

**From LC Tan 2020-01-16**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, whenever column F, H or J is selected, you want the value of the selected cell to be copied to column C on the same row.

This can be done in a number of ways, but here is a simple example that tests if the selected column is between 6 and 15 (F and O, can be changed), and then tests if the value in the target is a number (the count). It then copies the current cell to column C on the same row as the selected cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub

If Target.Column < 6 Or Target.Column > 15 Then Exit Sub
If Not IsNumeric(Target) Then Range("C" & Target.Row).Value = Target.Value

End Sub
```

There are a fair few other ways to do it, but this should get you well on your way.

Comment: To Plutian  Thank you very much for your example. It works beautifully. Thank you. From Tan LC 2020-01-19